# $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u+f(x)} dx= a \exp(b u)$, solve $f(x)$

Tags: integration

$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u+f(x)} dx= a \exp(b u)$, solve $f(x)$.

I want the integral at left is equal to the form of $a \exp(b u)$. Here $a$ and $b$ are just some parameters or constants, they both can be 1 for simplicity.

(1)What method should I use to solve this kind of problem?

Or

(2) Which specific form of f(x) can satisfy the above condition?

Comment: Where is the question from?

Comment: @Sal, this question is from a statistical problem in physics. Here $u$ is chemical potential, and the integral is a kind a particle numbers $N$. $f(x)$ the energy levels, and $1/(u+f(x))$ is a Rayleigh-Jeans distribution. I wish $N$ and $u$ can have a relation like $N \sim \exp(bu)$.

Comment: Seems like you have a nonlinear integral equation for $f$. I do not have an answer. Some thoughts: If $a, \ b, \ f$ do not depend on $u$, and the equality is to hold for all $u$, you can equate the power series (in $u$) of LHS and RHS. This leads to a sequence of integral equations: $\int\limits_0^1 dx \ g^n(x)=\frac{a(-b)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$ where $g(x)=1/f(x)$. It is not obvious to me if such a function exists. On the other hand, if you only require $\int_0^1 dx /(u+f)\sim ae^{bu}$ as $u\to u_0$ then one could find approximate candidate $f$, but you need to specify $u_0$ (is it $0$? infinity?)